# Why am I not restricted from instantiating abstract classes in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, abstraction, python-3.4

I have written a Python script and just found out that Python 3.4 does not restrict an abstract class from being instantiated while Python 2.7.8 did.

Here is my abstract class in the file named `Shape.py`.

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Shape:

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta # Making the class abstract

    def __init__(self):
        pass:

    @abstractmethod
    def getArea(self):
        print("You shouldn't have called me.")
        return None
```

Now I created another class that inherits from the `abstract` class `Shape`:
Filename: `Circle.py`

```
from Shape import Shape

class Circle(Shape):

    PI = 3.141

    def __init__(self, radius=0):
        self.radius = radius

    def getArea(self):    # Overriding it from Shape class
        return self.PI * self.radius ** 2
```

Now in my `Main.py`:

```
from Shape import Shape
from Circle import Circle

shape = Shape() # This gave me errors in Python 2.7.8 but not in Python 3.4
shape2 = Circle(5) 

print("Area of shape = "+str(shape.getArea()))    # This should have not been executed.
print("Area of circle = "+str(shape2.getArea()))
```

This `Main.py` gives errors on commented areas in Python2.7.8 but works fine on Python3.4.
Output on Python3.4:

```
You shouldn't have called me
Area of shape = None
Area of circle = 78.525
```

1. Why is this happening? This is not what abstraction is! Is it?
2. Or has there been any new way introduced for abstraction in Python 3.4?
3. Can any one give me the link of official documentation for python 3.4?

Comment: you could use six.add_meta_class decorator to support both Python 2 & 3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python 3, you declare a metaclass differently:

```
class Shape(metaclass=ABCMeta):
```

See the [*Customizing class creation* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses):

> The class creation process can be customised by passing the `metaclass` keyword argument in the class definition line, or by inheriting from an existing class that included such an argument.

All examples in the [`abc` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) for Python 3 also use the correct notation.

This was changed to give metaclasses a chance to get involved with class creation earlier than was possible in Python 2; see [PEP 3115](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3115/).

The `__metaclass__` attribute has no special meaning anymore, so you didn't actually create a proper abstract class.

Demo with Python 3.4:

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
>>> class Shape(metaclass=ABCMeta):
...     @abstractmethod
...     def getArea(self):
...         print("You shouldn't have called me.")
...         return None
... 
>>> Shape()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Shape with abstract methods getArea
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. How silly of me. Can you please answer my third sub question too(edited question)? Thanks for help in advance.